# Firebase Cloud Notification shows 0 opens 0 clicks

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Firebase Cloud Notifications for Push Notifications in my iOS App written in Swift.

Although, the notifications are working as expected and I can see the Number of Deliveries, It doesn't show the Open Count and Click Count.

I have searched for similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them has been answered yet.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the number of sends is being tracked but not Open Count or other things.

Any Help is Appreciated.

[image: Here is an actual report of my app]

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and it was caused by the missing Firebase Analytics library.

Documentation [for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup):

> Step 4: Add Firebase SDKs to your app
> ...
> 4. Choose the Firebase libraries you want to use.
> If Google Analytics is enabled in your Firebase project, make sure to add
> FirebaseAnalytics. For Analytics without IDFA collection capability, add
> FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdId instead.

Documentation [for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

> Step 4: Add Firebase SDKs to your app
> ...
> // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

Google Analytics also has a setup guide in the Admin UI (Admin - Property - Data Streams, select the stream, click "SDK Setup Instructions"):

[image]